# How can I keep the image highlighted upon click, even after browser refresh?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Basically, I have 3 images: I tried to assign 'focus' to them so as to create a border around the image upon click. However, I want the following - if possible - to happen:

1. Every image I click stays highlighted, and then when I refresh the browser they clicked ones stay highlighted.

or

1. Clicked image stay highlighed even after the browser has refreshed.

```css
a:focus img
{
  border:1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><img src="http://cdn.s7.disneystore.com/is/image/DisneyShopping/1344039601602?$yetidetail$" alt=""  /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="http://cdn.s7.disneystore.com/is/image/DisneyShopping/1344039601602?$yetidetail$" alt=""  /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="http://cdn.s7.disneystore.com/is/image/DisneyShopping/1344039601602?$yetidetail$" alt=""  /></a>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: cookies and javascript

Comment: Use the web storage of the browser. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: I am having difficulties seeing a difference between the two options. Can you elaborate?

Comment: How do you use localstorage with styles?!

Comment: @EmadSMoses You can't. Using localstorage is outside the purview of CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the "visited" selector?

```
a:visited img, image:visited {
  # Awesome styling right here!
}
```

Comment: The :visited selector works on 'a' elements even when the page is close and re-opend/refreshed. Since he is wrapping the image in an 'a' element he should be able to use this selector to achieve his goal.

Comment: I know what `:visited` does, but have you tried it?

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried :visited, :focus...etc.. nothing works!